# How can i check in MS SQL Server 2005 if a column is of a specific type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to change the type of a column in MS SQL Server 2005, but before i change the type of that column i want to check if that column is of the type i want to change. How can i do that in SQL?

Thanxs,
Bas Hendriks.

Based on the anwser i wrote the following query that did the trick:

```
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'e_application'
            AND COLUMN_NAME = 'txt_locked_by'
            AND DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar'
            AND CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = 15 )
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE.....
        END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3508881/SQL-Server-2005-System-Tables-and-Views.htm) tables.

E.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sp_help TableName` , it also retrieve's the column's data types and other properties