# View Column Type in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a view and would like to find out how a specific column is defined i.e. is it INTEGER or VARCHAR or something else.
How can I do that on MS SQL Server?

Comment: read about sys.columns (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) and sys.views (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190334.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i check in MS SQL Server 2005 if a column is of a specific type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855446/how-can-i-check-in-ms-sql-server-2005-if-a-column-is-of-a-specific-type)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (fill in your own (fill in the schema,tablename and columname) :

```
select data_type from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_SCHEMA='xxx' and TABLE_NAME='yyy' and COLUMN_NAME='zzz'
```